# error FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: java, mysql, sql, syntax-error

I am working on some select queries and am getting the error FROM keyword not found where expected in my last query, and I cant figure out what the problem is.

```
ResultSet rs4 = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(UnitPrice) AS 'Total'"
    + "FROM" 
    + " orderdetails INNER JOIN orders ON orderdetails.OrderID = orders.OrderID"
    + " WHERE customerID = 'LILAS'"
    + "GROUP BY customerid"
    + "HAVING SUM((UnitPrice * Quantity) - (UnitPrice * Quantity * discount)) > "
    + " ( SELECT AVG(SUM((UnitPrice * Quantity) - (UnitPrice * Quantity * discount)))"
    + "AS avg('AMOUNT')"
    + "FROM orderdetails"
    +" GROUP BY UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount)");

System.out.println("# of Orders for this customer < average order amount for all customers =" + rs4.getString(1));
```

Comment: Hint: print out your SQL. It doesn't look like you think it does.

Comment: ^ As another hint, make sure you're checking that you have white space in all the correct spots. (Okay, maybe that one's more of a give away).

Comment: Hint: use a `StringBuilder` and do not concatenate strings.

Answer (score 0):

Error 1: Looks like you're missing a space between `AS 'Total'"` and `"FROM"` in your string concatenation, which is causing the syntax error.

Error 2: In the line `"AS avg('AMOUNT')`, `avg` is a reserved keyword for the `AVERAGE` function. your current usage is trying to invoke the function call. Hence, if you want to set the column alias as "avg(AMOUNT)", try changing that line to 
`"AS 'avg(AMOUNT)'`.

Comment: I have an eeror on AS AVG(AMOUNT)